# Как создать класс в котором будет шаблонный указатель на разные типы

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Класс управляющий экранами.

```
  class ScreenStack final
  {
  public:
    explicit ScreenStack(std::initializer_list
        <std::unique_ptr<IUserMenu<?>>> &list_menu)
    {
      for (auto& element : list_menu) 
      {
        screens_.emplace(std::move(element.get())); 
      }

    }

  private:
    std::stack<std::unique_ptr<IUserMenu<?>>> screens_;
  }
```

Класс который является интерфейсом для наследников

```
  template < typename T >
  class IUserMenu
  {
  protected:

    // Displays the screen interface to the user
    virtual void display_interface() const = 0;

    // title, body, select
    virtual void print_title() const = 0;
    virtual void print_body() const = 0;
    virtual void print_select() const = 0;

    // Reads user select input
    std::unique_ptr<IStandartReader<T>> reader_;

    std::vector<std::tuple<T, std::string>> choices_;
    std::string location_name_;
  public:
    virtual ~IUserMenu() {}
  };
```

Класс насленик IUserMenu

```
  class MainMenu final : public IUserMenu<short>
  {
  public:
    MainMenu()  noexcept;
    virtual void display_interface() const override;

  
  private:
    // title, body, select
    virtual void print_title() const override;
    virtual void print_body() const override;
    virtual void print_select() const override;

  /* IUserMenu 
   // std::vector<std::tuple<T, std::string>> choices_;
   // std::unique_ptr<IStandartReader<short>> reader_;
   // std::string location_name_;
  */
  };
```

Как правильно сделать чтобы создавая класс ScreenStack инициализировать разными интерфейсами с шаблонным парамером которые унаследованы от него

```
auto screen_stack{ ScreenStack({std::make_unique<AltMenu>() /*std::string*/, std::make_unique<MainMenu>() /* short*/}) };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не очень понятно, почему в интерфейсе вообще поля.

Можно вынести поля в шаблонного потомка - тогда интерфейс можно сделать нешаблонным, и проблема пропадает.